# Rally: java application has started to throw an exception, recently

Tags: java, rally

I started using my java application after about two weeks and now I see the following exception everytime I run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doRequest(RallyRestApi.java:258)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doPost(RallyRestApi.java:276)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.update(RallyRestApi.java:155)
    at ExportTRtoRally.testresult_to_testset(ExportTRtoRally.java:273)
    at ExportTRtoRally.main(ExportTRtoRally.java:453)
```

It is happening when the testresults are being added to testset as shown above.
The application has been working fine in the past.
Does anyone know the reason for it?

Here is the testresult_to_testset() method:

```
public static void testresult_to_testset(RallyRestApi r, ArrayList<String> testres_refs,      String testset_ref) throws IOException{

    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------\nAdding test results to the testset...");
    for (String i2 : testres_refs){
        JsonObject tingo2 = new JsonObject();
        tingo2.addProperty("TestSet", testset_ref);
        UpdateRequest req = new UpdateRequest(i2, tingo2);
        UpdateResponse resp = r.update(req);
        if(resp.wasSuccessful())
            System.out.println(resp.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------------------\nTestResults successfully added to TestSet\n----------------------------------");
}
```

Thanks,
Haris

Comment: You're going to have to show more code if you would like an answer. Specifically the `testresult_to_testset` method.

Comment: testresult_to_testset method added.

Comment: It successfully added some testresults to testset but fails in the middle somewhere. e.g., out of 700 testresults , it added 300 and then failed...